# Java - instance variables mysteriously becoming null in same thread

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, null, instance

I've come across something in Java that has me really scratching my head trying to figure out what's going on.

I create an object objA and in its constructor I add this object to another object objB:

```
objB.addListener(this);
```

Later, a method is called on objA, which calls out to a method in objB, which then calls back on objA:

**objA.doSomething() => objB.doSomethingAlso => objA.doSomethingElse()**

```
objA.doSomething();
```

In objA:

```
public void doSomething() {
    _instanceVar = initInstanceVar();
    objB.doSomethingAlso();
}
```

In objB:

```
public void doSomethingAlso() {
    ...
    getRefToObjA().doSomethingElse();
}
```

In objA again:

```
public void doSomethingElse() {
    _instanceVar.someMethod();
}
```

However, when doSomethingElse() is called, _instanceVar (an instance variable!) is now null. It was initialized to a non-null value in doSomething()...so how can it be null now? It is not being explicitly set to null anywhere. And all these method calls (as far as is obvious to me) are occurring in the same thread.

What am I missing here? How can that instance variable be null?

Comment: Can you show all of your code?

Comment: If it is a threading issue, every detail counts - you should post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What's inside : initInstanceVar();?

Comment: Probably you are passing an uninitialized object reference (during construction) where `_instanceVar` was `null` when it was read.

Comment: I'd say the problem comes from the objA reference you're trying to get in `doSomethingAlso()` via the call to `getRefToObjA()`. Maybe this does not return the objA you expect. Please show more code as @assylias asked, so that we can help (although I don't think it is a threading issue).

Comment: Is your `getRefToObjA()` method something like this? `public Object getRefToObjA() { objARef.setInstanceVar(null); return objARef; }` Without more detail it's hard to guess what the issue is.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning. 1. Why don't you call initInstanceVar() only once in the constructor? 2. Couldn't this be solved more elegant and easier with inheritance?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `Object _instanceVar = initInstanceVar();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 2 things can happen here

1. `initInstanceVar();` returns null
2. Somehow the variable gets cleaned by garbage collector